# .htaccess: Slugs and file extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm looking for a way to disable access to file, if not accessed through slug. for example, I have `/members.php?page=login`. I want to change it, by forcing the user access `/login` (redirect the long url into a short slug) and prevent direct access from the long url.

When I try to do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^members.php?page=login login [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^login members.php?page=login [L]
```

It turns into an infinite loop (as firefox says: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.").

I've enabled the "options" at the beginning of file (`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`)

How can I make it right?

Thanks.

Comment: Why should you want to disable usage of the long url? There is absolutely no reason for that.

Comment: @arkascha I prefer to use slugs instead of full url, if possible

Comment: That is true, we got that. But that has nothing to do with disabling the long version. That is a measure on top of using pretty URLs. And, as said, there is no real reason for that. Why should you invest into that? Nothing bad happens if someone (whyever) uses the long version.

Comment: @arkascha You right - but - I think that pretty urls are easy to remember and to access. In forms, for example, if I must use `members.php?page=login` I will write it this way but I want that just `login` will work in the form. by the way excuse my english if I had any misspellings

Comment: You don't get the point. You think too complex. Certainly you want to use short URLs. They are usually referred to as "pretty URLs" or "SEO friendly URLs", not really as "slugs". And if you do then all is fine. Publish a link to your site in such short form and the users will use them. There is no reason why they should use the long versions, since they are not given such a link. All I am saying is that you should not invest effort into trying to prevent users from using long URLs. They won't anyway. So why prevent it? You do not gain anything by that, you just make things more complex.

Comment: The point is: you should only publish short URLs, never long URLs. But that has _nothing_ to do with preventing long URLs from working fine.

Comment: @arkascha I do get the point, I just don't know really how to explain myself. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
# externally redirect "/members.php?page=login" to "/login"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /members\.php\?page=login [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login [L,R]
#rewrite "/login" back to "/members.php?page=login"
RewriteRule ^login members.php?page=login [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?page=login [L]
```